# find input with name attribute is not working - jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to find the child input with name="test".

find("input[name='test']") doesnot work however if I use class instead of name it works, why?

Thanks in advance.

Html:

```
<div class="test-div">
    <div id="test-click"></div>
    <input type="text" class="test" name="test[]" required="">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#test-click").on('click', function() {

    let parentDiv = $(this).closest(".test-div");

    let testInput = parentDiv.find("input.test").val(); 
    console.log(testInput);   //it works
            
    let testInput1 = parentDiv.find("input[name='test']").val(); 
    console.log(testInput1);   //gives undefined
}
```

Comment: Your input name is not test. It is test[]

Comment: Please correct your name attribute value to `test`

Comment: Or use `input[name='test[]']`